# Probability of Men Hair Growth

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> The following stats are known:
>
> Before reaching 55, 50% of men will have hair loss
>
> Before reaching 55, 70% of men will have greying hair
>
> Before reaching 55, 30% of men will have hair loss greying hair
>
> Based on these stats what is the probability before the age of 55 a randomly selected man will experience some level of balding or some level of greying?
>
> A randomly selected man before the age of 55 experiences balding or greying, what is the probability before the age of 55 he experiences both balding and greying?

So these questions confuse me in multiple ways.  For the first question I did $P(Loss or Grey)=P(Loss)+P(Grey)-P(Loss and Grey)=.5+.7-.3=.9$

However for the second question it is asking for the probability, $P(Loss and Grey)$, but don't we have that from the figures given above, which would be $30$ percent?  I must not be understanding the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the desired probability must be described as conditional. So we have $$P=\Pr\{\text{becoming grey-haired and bald}|\text{becoming grey-haired or bald}\}\\={\Pr\{\text{becoming grey-haired and bald}\}\over \Pr\{\text{becoming grey-haired or bald}\}}$$

Comment: Okay so the second part would be $1/3$.  Does this mean my first part is correct, .9 so I can just plug it into here

Comment: Yes. It is correct.